# Formalidad de "Tu mujer"

Tags: formalidad

So I saw this tweet on Twitter:

[image]

Which for me raises the question of formality and dialect uses of "tu mujer" vs. "tu esposa". Is one more formal than the other? I ask because I know that "tu mujer" translates literally to "your woman" (though it does seem to be linguistically correct to use it as "your wife"). Is there a difference in Spanish dialects (e.g. Latin American Spanish)  as to how "tu mujer" is interpreted vs. "tu esposa"?

Comment: I'm new in this site, I can write here always in Spanish or there are some rules about this?

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer you can write in Spanish as long as the question is relative, I'm just not good enough with Spanish to try to put the whole post in Spanish without sounding all sorts of wrong haha. Hopefully that will change soon.

Comment: So, if the question is only in spanish I can post my answer only in spanish?

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer I don't think it matters as long as you answer the question in a helpful manner, don't quote me on that though.

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer You can check out the help center for more info on that: [Answer]

Comment: And, it's not necesarily your wife, it can be your girlfriend or your crush or even a girl who you are very close to, even if you are gay!, but in those cases can even sound a little bit ironic, more like saying you are almost a couple but you aren't.

Comment: @Jaime So...for lack of a better example it's kind of like the slang term "wifey". Where you would refer to someone you are in a significant commitment (or delusional interest) with but not necessarily married officially?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use "tu mujer" when refers to your wife, but "tu esposa" is more formal. By example when I go to present my wife to another person I never say "Les presento a mi mujer" I say "Les presento a mi esposa".

"Tu mujer" is not the same as "Tú, mujer", in this case "Tu mujer" is "Your wife" and "Tú, mujer" is "You, woman", because in this case you are making reference to a specific woman when you say "Tú".

Remember that in Spanish an  accent can change the signification of the word.

So in this case "Tu mujer es un mono" is "Your wife is a monkey", and really this phrase is bizarre!

Comment: It is a bizarre phrase lol, but there's many of those on Duolingo! It definitely took me a while to get the hang of the difference between "Tú" and "Tu" when I first learned "Tu" and "Su" but yes accents do make a difference! Another example of that is "papa" and "papá". Big difference between those! Thank you for the formality explanation!

Answer (score 2):

"Mi mujer" is preferred pretty much exclusively in Castillian Spanish. Almost no one in Spain would say "esposa": it would feel like listening to a poet.

Comment: @fedorqui: There was no need to edit the question.

Comment: Apart from the semi colon, there was a typo: `"esposa,"`. http://spanish.stackexchange.com/posts/15486/revisions

Comment: @Prof.JoséF.Martínez so even in a formal situation one would introduce their wife as "mi mujer" in Spain?

Comment: @fedorqui Comma inside quotes is the preferred way in American English, is it not?

Comment: @Douglas_Symb Correct!

Comment: Prof.JoséF.Martínez to the debate you are having with @fedorqui your punctuation marks would be outside of the quotes because they are used to structure a sentence outside of the quotations marks. You are only using the quotation marks to quote "esposa", so his edit was correct. To the original topic, I was considering keeping "dialect" as a tag in this post, but I edited it because it didn't seem like a dialect issue but now it seems it might be if you are saying that "Mi Mujer" is used often in Spain. Now I want to know if it is used in Latin Spanish like that.

Comment: @Douglas_Symb: No idea about Latin American usage of "mi mujer." Commas and periods always inside quotes in the US: "Periods and commas precede closing quotation marks, whether double or single" - Chicago Manual of Style, 16th edition, Chicago: University of Chicago Press, 2010.

Comment: It seems the other person who answered, who according to his biography is from Cuba, says he introduces his wife in a formal setting as "Mi esposa." According to [Perdue Owl](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/577/03/) in APA style you're correct about putting periods and comma's inside quotation marks (learned something new, I had no idea). However in your answer that was a colon (semi-colon originally) so it would proceed the quotation marks. I might open up a question about this on English Stack Exchange because I guess that APA/Chicago/MLA doesn't always follow grammar rules.